# Modals Bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I past into a new page the [live demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>



<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

but it doen't work. Why?

In head section there are Bootstrap CSS and Javascript:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you include the required `bootstrap.js` dependency as well?

Comment: you will have to include jquery.js before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you've included jquery as well?

It needs to come before bootstrap.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">`

Notice `data-target="#myModal"`. Notice also that your modal is `<div class="modal fade">` (without an id).

Change `<div class="modal fade">` to `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">` and you should now see it pop up when you click the button.